# how to enable caches in u-boot for imx boards?

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, drivers

Since I am working on boot time optimization for imx boards , I heard enabling caches(D-cache or I-cache)  in u-boot causes improvements in boot performance.Can any one suggest the way to enable caches in u-boot for imx boards.Enabling caches will make any damage to the board?

Comment: I get what u-boot is, but what is an imx board one of those cortex dev boards? Could you clarify what D-caches and I-caches are? What OS are you running? What architecture are these boards? At the moment its a little hard to actually understand what the question is about, with lots of very domain specific things that might be understandable to a more general audience with more clarification.

Comment: Board I m using is mx53loco board.I read U-Boot doesn't enable D-Cache by default on ARM devices, as it needs customized MMU tables to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `dcache` and `icache` command.  If the commands aren't there, your u-boot is too old or the CPU doesn't support it.

To run it automatically, put it in your `bootcmd` environment variable.

Shouldn't damage the board.  If it locks up the CPU for some reason, just reset the board.